# Accessing Hovertext with html

Tags: python, html, graph, web-scraping, hover

I am trying to access hover text found on graph points at this site (bottom):

http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/TRLH1/1002200043?gameHash=b98e62c1bcc887e4&tab=overview

I have the full site html but I am unable to find the values displayed in the hover text. All that can be seen when inspecting a point are x and y values that are transformed versions of these values. The mapping can be determined with manual input taken from the hovertext but this defeats the purpose of looking at the html. Additionally, the mapping changes with each match history so it is not feasible to do this for a large number of games.

Is there any way around this?

thank you

Comment: It's quite possible that it's injected either via JavaScript, or CSS' `content` property. You can debug the hover state by right-clicking on the element in the Developer Tools and selecting `:hover`. Then you can see exactly where the text is coming from :)

Comment: I updated my answer, wbc, just wanted to make sure you've seen it.

Comment: thank you for the good advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Explanation

Nearly everything on this webpage is loaded via JSON through JavaScript.  We don't even have to request the original page.  You will, however, have to repiece together the page via id's of items, mysteries and etc., which won't be too hard because you can request masteries similar to how we **fetch items**.

So, I went through the *network tab in inspect* and I noticed that it loaded the following JSON formatted URL:

https://acs.leagueoflegends.com/v1/stats/game/TRLH1/1002200043?gameHash=b98e62c1bcc887e4

If you notice, there is a `gameHash` and the id (similar to that of the link you just sent me).  This page contains everything you need to rebuild it, given that you fetch all reliant JSON files.

## Dealing with JSON

You can use `json.loads` in Python to load it, but a great tool I would recomend is:

https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

You copy and paste JSON in there and it will  help you understand the data structure.

## Fetching items

The webpage loads all this information via a JSON file:

https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.10.1/data/en_US/item.json

It contains all of the information and tool tips about each item in the game. You can access your desired item via: `theirJson['data']['1001']`.  Each image on the page's file name is the id (or `1001`) in this example.

For instance, for `'Boots of Speed'`:

```
import requests, json

itemJson = json.loads(requests.get('https://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.10.1/data/en_US/item.json').text)
print(itemJson['data']['1001'])
```

## An alternative: Selenium

Selenium could be used for this.  You should look it up.  It's been ported for several programming languages, one being Python.  It may work as you want it to here, but I sincerely think that the JSON method (describe above), although a little more convoluted, will perform faster (since speed, based on your post, seems to be an important factor).

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer! I have been using selenium for my work so far but i had trouble with this section. Your JSON instructions seem very promising I will try them out first thing tomorrow

Comment: To follow up, this worked perfectly for what i wanted out of the website. Thank you for the help

Comment: Hey, if you could mark as solution and upvote, it'd help a lot.  Thanks.